# UART read blocks after reading 33 bytes

Tags: c

I have made a C-program flash image to micro controller through uart.In this code,i am following a protocol,all things are going well.But when i load image into micro controller through uart,write is working fine but read blocked after reading 33 bytes.I am writing and reading byte by byte..declaration & definition of function to load image is written below:

Function declaration :

**load_RAM_image(file_size, file_buff);**

here file_size is unsigned int and its value is 40,980KB and file_buff is unsigned char pointer which points to image buffer.

Function declaration :

```
#define BYTE_WRITE 1

#define DELAY 10000

int load_RAM_image(unsigned int buff_size, unsigned char *buff)
{
    unsigned int count, num_Wbytes, num_Rbytes, byte;
    for (count = 0; count < buff_size;)  /* increase count value to every time */
    { 
        num_Wbytes = write( serial_fd, buff + count, BYTE_WRITE );
        if (num_Wbytes < 0)
        {
            fputs("write failed!\n", stderr);
            return -1;
        }

        tcdrain(serial_fd);
        usleep(DELAY);
        num_Rbytes = read( serial_fd, rbuff + count, BYTE_WRITE );
        if (num_Rbytes < 0)
        {
            if (errno == EAGAIN)
            {
                printf("SERIAL EAGAIN ERROR\n");
                return -EAGAIN;
            }
            else
            {
                printf("SERIAL read error %d %s\n", errno, strerror(errno));
            }
        }

        printf("wbuf[ %d ] = %02x   rbuff = %02x\n\n", 
               count /*+ byte*/, *(buff + count/* + byte*/), rbuff[count]);

        /* Compare the received byte from BAM */
        if (strncmp(buff + count, rbuff + count, BYTE_WRITE ) < 0)
        {
            printf("Error : RAM loading error(W != R)\n");
            return -1;                      
        }

        count += BYTE_WRITE  ;
        printf("count = %d\n", count);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The read() and write() system calls return a **signed** quantity. Assigning it to an **unsigned** variable will do strange things. BTW: you are comparing an unsigned value with `(val < 0)` Your compiler should complain about that. The third argument to your `strncmp()` is also very wrong.

Comment: Have you tried block read and write instead of one byte at a time. Also what setting are you using for your serial connections?

Comment: No declaration for *rbuff* is visible.  The odds that it is big enough (buff_size) ought to be low.  This falls over when it starts writing past the end of rbuff.

Comment: @joop ...Changing the variable into signed,doesnt affect our output...it affect if there is any error in write function or read function.......

Comment: @praks411  ..Yes,firstly i tried block read and write but that also not working that's why i choose byte bye byte read and write...
Baud Rate---9600
none parity---
no flow control